# Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu Gnome 19.04

Tags: gnome, bluetooth, 19.04, bluez

I built my own PC a few months back however, both the sound and Bluetooth have not worked.

With Bluetooth, in settings, the option to turn on Bluetooth is greyed out and won't let me turn it on. If I go to the Bluetooth manager, I get the following message: "Connection to BlueZ failed. Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue."

Ran

```
 lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
```

Got this:

```
    06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 [8086:0010]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Ran:

```
rfkill list; dmesg | grep -i blue
```

Got this:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Ran:

```
lspci
```

Got this:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
01:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43d5 (rev 01)
01:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c8 (rev 01)
01:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c6 (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X] (rev ef)
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580]
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
08:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 145a
08:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
08:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] USB 3.0 Host controller
09:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1455
09:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
09:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: You never mentioned that you installed some BT adapter when building your PC. So why do you think it is there?

Comment: i did put in a BT adapter in my build. I installed an Asus wireless PCIE adapter with BT

Comment: There is no BT adapter in `Intel Corporation Wireless 8260`. It must be optional.

Comment: Please also add output of `rfkill list; dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: the exact adapter is: ASUS PCE-AC55BT B1 Wireless-AC1200 Bluetooth 4.2 PCIe/mPCIe adapter

Comment: You don't have a bluetooth adapter. Maybe it is fake. Let's check `lspci` too.

Comment: Even on the Asus website it says there should be bluetooth

Comment: https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/PCE-AC55BT-B1/

Comment: Please post output of `lspci`.

Comment: It is a weird device that doesn't show a separate BT device anywhere. I don't think BT will work on Linux soon.

Answer (score 0):

This Asus  PCE-AC55BT B1 device doesn't have Linux drivers for bluetooth yet.

There is only Windows driver for BT at Asus site.

The BT device isn't shown in `lsusb` that makes it difficult to support on kernel level. There must be some hacky Windows driver.

I suggest to return it to seller. Linux support is declared, but it is a cheat.